# How to add a MvvmViewModel in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: mvvm-light

I just installed MvvmLight for Visual Studio 2017 on different machines.
I didn't found the possibility to add a new ViewModel in my project as was in Visual studio 2015.
Is this functionality not implemented in Visual Studio 2017 ?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is no mismatch in your project type to Mvvm WPF? Or maybe a .NET Framework mismatch?

Comment: I tried with two computers and with different versions of visual studio, i also tried with a visual studio 2015 project and the problem is the same.

Comment: Please check the type of project you created (Is it a WPF project?) and which .NET Framework version your project is targeting. It might well be that your .NET target Framework is not supported by MvvmLight.

Comment: Nope, these templates do not appear for me either using VS2017 and a WPF Project with .NET 4.5.1.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up going to the project's [MVVM Light Github Site](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight) and downloading the repository as a zip file.

Once the file is downloaded, I extracted it and copied the contents of ~\Downloads\mvvmlight-master\mvvmlight-master\Templates\CSharp\ItemTemplates into ~\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C#.